# Differential equations and optics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is a problem in Mathematical Methods by Mary L. Boas book (Prob.8.4.20) that I couldn't understand what it asking me to do.

> Find the shape of a mirror which has the property that rays from a point $O$ on the axis are reflected into a parallel beam.
>
> Hint: Take the point $O$ at the origin. Show from the figure that $\tan 2\theta = y/x$. Use the formula for $\tan 2\theta$ to express this in terms of $\tan \theta = dx/dy$ and solve the resulting differential equation.
>
> (Hint: See Problem 16.)

I think it is asking me to use $\tan 2\theta = y/x$ to solve the differential equation $\tan \theta=dy/dx$. Is this correct?

If not, is there any idea that may help me to understand how to write a differential equation that will represents the case?

Answer (score 1):

The relation $\tan2θ=y/x$ defines what $θ$ is. This can be used in the differential equation $\tanθ=dy/dx$ to eliminate $θ$.

You can use the double angle relation
$$
\tan2θ=\frac{2\tanθ}{1-\tan^2θ}.
$$
Problem 16 is about an DE (perhaps even this one) that is of the Clairaut type $u=xu'+f(u')$ after substitution.

Comment: I think the differential equation would be for $y(x)$, because $\tan \theta = dy/dx \neq dx\dy$.

Comment: Yes, I was misled by the typo in the quoted problem where it is $dx/dy$. It is correct in the original.

Answer (score 1):

A picture of ray trace while under reflection is helpful.

[image: ReflnOptics]

$$ \tan 2\theta = \frac{PX}{XO}=\frac{y}{x}$$

$$ \phi= \pi/2-\theta,\quad \tan \phi= \cot \theta = \frac{1}{\tan \theta}= \frac{dy}{dx}$$

In order to set up DE of reflector now find

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\tan \phi = \cot \theta =f(\tan 2 \theta)= f(x,y) $$ using double angle formula.